# Having trouble implementing placeholder in textfield that has select prop. (MUI 5)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I have created a textfield for a react app I am building. As you can see in the codesandbox below, there are 2 different textfields with a set placeholder. However, only in the first textfield the placeholder is being applied and not in the second one. The second one has a select prop, which i looked through the documentation and did not find an answer to this question. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Please see this codesandbox for the code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mui-forked-dvp21b?file=/index.js)

In summary, for some reason placeholder='Enter dog's name' is being applied as intended.

However, placeholder="Select dog size" is not being applied for some reason.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you need to use a text field for the select? It looks like a MUI Select (https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/) would work fine. Instead of using a placeholder, you could say `value={dog.size}`

Comment: I actually started out trying to use MUI Select. The reason why I switched to textfield, is the styling of mui select was extremely difficult and frustrating. With all these nested elements I did not figure out how to make it look the way I wanted to. With the textfield everything is working as intended except for the placeholder

Comment: I have the exact same question. Did you ever get a solution?